# Como puedo guardar archivos dentro de una carpeta temporal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

perdonen si esto es una pregunta tonta, pero les explico. Estoy obteniendo el directorio de la carpeta `temp` o `tmp`, y a ésta creándole una carpeta llamada "ImagenesTemporales", la cual como dice el nombre, solamente la voy a utilizar para guardar imágenes con baja resolución de manera temporal.

El problema es que se "ImagenesTemporales" se está creando con éxito, pero las imágenes no se están guardando dentro de ésta, y no entiendo donde le estoy pifiando.

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Éste código recibe una lista de imágenes traídas desde una base de datos. Con "TemporalFolder()" creo u obtengo el directorio de la carpeta temporal, y con la funcion "SaveImage()" le estoy enviando el nombre de la imagen, el directorio de la carpeta, y el nuevo tamaño de la imagen.

```
private void CambiarTamañoImagen(List<PedidoViewModel> pedidoViewModels)
        {
            const int thumbnailWidth = 500;
            string tempFolder;

            try
            {
                tempFolder = TemporalFolder();

                foreach (var item in pedidoViewModels)
                {
                    var imageResult = Image.Load("wwwroot/" + item.getImagenes());

                    this.SaveImage(imageResult, tempFolder, thumbnailWidth);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.error = ex.Message.ToString();
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Con esta funcion busco guardar la imagen dentro de la carpeta temporal:

```
private void SaveImage(Image image, string name, int resizeWidth)
{
    var width = image.Width;
    var height = image.Height;

    if (width > resizeWidth)
    {
        height = (int)((double)resizeWidth / width * height);
        width = resizeWidth;
    }

    image
        .Mutate(i => i.Resize(new Size(width, height)));

    image.Metadata.ExifProfile = null;

    image.SaveAsJpeg(name, new JpegEncoder
    {
        Quality = 100
    });
}
```

Ésta es la funcion para crear y obtener la carpeta temporal:

```
private string TemporalFolder()
{
    DirectoryInfo result = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetTempPath() + @"ImagenesTemporales");

    return result.FullName;
}
```

**Actualizacion:**

Haga lo que haga ya sea localmente o en produccion, voy a tener este error:

> System.Exception: Access to the path 'C:\Users\Users\source\repos\DesarrolloWebLogistica\WebLogistica\wwwroot\ImagenesTemporales\imgAndroid\imagen' is denied. at WebLogistica.Controllers.HomeController.CambiarTamañoImagen(List`1 pedidoViewModels) in C:\Users\Users\source\repos\DesarrolloWebLogistica\WebLogistica\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 289 at WebLogistica.Controllers.HomeController.VerPedido(String identi) in C:\Users\Users\source\repos\DesarrolloWebLogistica\WebLogistica\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 157

Es decir, el acceso a la carpeta está denegado, intenté darme acceso pero tampoco me deja.

Ahora intento guardar las imágenes en memoria pero todos los códigos de ejemplo utilizan `Bitmap` o `Encode`, y los warnings de Visual Studio me dicen que son solamente soportados en `Windows`, y mi proyecto está alojado en `Linux`

Sinceramente no sé qué hacer, estoy hace unos dias con éste mismo problema y no puedo resolverlo.

Comment: ¿Qué ruta te genera en ese `result.FullName`?

Comment: Tienes el nombre de la carpeta, pero el nombre de la imagen???

Comment: El nombre de la imagen está en item.getImagenes()

Comment: `result.FullName` me trae la ruta completa temporal + la carpeta que quiero crear: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ImagenesTemporales` @fredyfx

Comment: ¿Y si creas una carpeta llamada "ImagenesTemporales" en la mismo nivel de `wwwroot` ?

Comment: Lo mismo que el problema: `System.Exception: Access to the path 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\DesarrolloWebLogistica\WebLogistica\WebLogistica\ImagenesTemporales' is denied`, Lamentablemente nosé cómo arreglarlo.

Comment: Click derecho, propiedades... Seguridad... Añadir usuario...

Comment: si, tampoco me dejo, se lo puse a todas las carpetas hasta llegar a la C:

Comment: ¿Le estás colocando el usuario del IIS?

Comment: Si, tengo el usuario IIS y tambien Todos

Answer (score 2):

Como bien dices, si result.FullName te trae la ruta completa temporal + la carpeta que quieres crear: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ImagenesTemporales
entonces el método:

```
private void CambiarTamañoImagen(List<PedidoViewModel> pedidoViewModels)
{
   const int thumbnailWidth = 500;
   string tempFolder;

   try
   {
      tempFolder = TemporalFolder();
      // En este punto tempFolder vale:
      // "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ImagenesTemporales"

      foreach (var item in pedidoViewModels)
      {
         var imageResult = Image.Load("wwwroot/" + item.getImagenes());
         // Y en este punto estás mandando a guardar la imagen sólo con la ruta
         // cuando tendría que ser tempFolder + "/" + filename
         // donde 'filename' es el nombre del archivo a guardar.
         this.SaveImage(imageResult, tempFolder, thumbnailWidth);
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      ViewBag.error = ex.Message.ToString();
      throw new Exception(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: es decir, quedaria  this.SaveImage(imageResult, tempFolder + "/" + filename, thumbnailWidth);?

Comment: asi ahora tengo este error: `System.Exception: Could not find a part of the path '/tmp/ImagenesTemporales/imgAndroid/2022/09/01/966844_80904045_0046-00273329_2022-09-01_16-39-29.jpg'.` Pero bueno creo que es porque no existe el path

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!